# What is orphaned message in IoT hub and what it indicates

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

When I first register a device with DPS and send telemetry message, it works successfully, after some time or maybe after some days, when I send the same message again with or without re-registration, that message became orphaned as my event hub not getting that message and hence my function is not triggered.

Please guide my what is orphaned message and how it reproduces? Also how to fix these issues?

My workflow is as below.
Device Register:
- Device Register through DPS to IoT hub
- In IoT hub, there is message routing query which routes a message to the event hub
- There is one function, which triggered based on that event hub.

Comment: Could you please provide the routing query you have written for the message route in IoT hub?

Comment: Yes sure @YatinGaikwad, here it is. 

$body.type="registration" or $body.type="deviceUpdate"

Comment: Message orphan occur when the message do not match the routing rule, If the body of message is something like this {"type":"regsitration/deviceUpdate"} then I suspect you are mistaking somewhere in the routing endpoints.

Comment: Hi, @YatinGaikwad, Thanks for the quick reply. Can you explain in more detail? As I have verified multiple times that my routing endpoints are correct, as it is working for other devices of the same type, but it stops after a few days for a particular device